# Etwas zur Seite schieben

Tags: phrase, verb-usage

> Er hat gestern an den Selbstmord gedacht, aber er hat es zur Seite geschoben.

Gibt es weitere Möglichkeiten, *etwas zur Seite schieben* zu schreiben? Ich habe versucht, nach weiteren Möglichkeiten im Netz oder in Büchern zu suchen, aber ich habe nichts gefunden.

Habt ihr Vorschläge?

Comment: ich würde in dem Beispiel schreiben "... er hat *den Gedanken* aber *beiseite* (oder zur Seite) geschoben", das klingt für mich natürlicher.

Comment: *...hat den Gedanken aber verdrängt* oder *...ist aber wieder davon abgekommen* oder *...hat es sich dann doch anders überlegt* - Wobei "beiseiteschieben" und die anderen Ausdrücke eher zu etwas Nebensächlicherem passen als ausgerechnet zu Selbstmord.

Comment: Er hat gestern an [den] Selbstmord gedacht, es/den Gedanken aber dann verworfen.

Comment: Vielleicht kannst du noch genauer beschreiben, was du ausdrücken willst. *Einen Gedanken zur Seite schieben* bedeutet ja, dass man ihn vorerst nicht weiter verfolgt, aber noch nicht vollständig aufgibt - es besteht die Absicht, ihn später wieder aufzunehmen. Ist dir dieser Aspekt wichtig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Wort »*es*« in dem Beispielsatz würde ich durch »*diese Absicht*« oder »*den Gedanken daran*« ersetzen. Beim »*es*« ist nicht ganz klar, worauf es sich bezieht:

> Er hat gestern an den Selbstmord gedacht, aber er hat *diese Absicht* zur Seite geschoben.
>   Er hat gestern an den Selbstmord gedacht, aber er hat *den Gedanken daran* zur Seite geschoben.

Auch das »*zur Seite schieben*« ist unpassend in diesem Fall. Man schiebt eher etwas zur Seite oder beiseite, das einem lästig ist:

> Gerd sollte eigentlich das Garagentor reparieren, aber er schob den Gedanken daran beiseite und ging stattdessen zu Heinz um mit ihm ein Bier zu trinken.

Selbstmord ist keine lästige Pflicht, sondern etwas, das man freiwillig (wenn auch aus unerfreulichen Gründen) macht. Daher ist »*zur Seite schieben*« hier stilistisch bedenklich.

Wenn mit »etwas zur Seite schieben« nicht gemeint ist, dass man einen physischen Gegenstand unter Aufwendung von körperlicher Kraft ungefähr rechtwinkelig zu einem Weg bewegt, dann fallen mir folgende ähnliche Formulierungen ein, die jedoch auch leicht abweichende Bedeutungen haben:

- **etwas zur Seite schieben** (einer lästigen Verpflichtung vorübergehend nicht nachkommen)
- **etwas beiseite schieben** (identische Bedeutung wie »zur Seite schieben«)
- **etwas aufschieben** (den ursprünglichen Plan nicht aufgeben, sondern ihn später erledigen wollen)
- **etwas verdrängen** (nicht mehr an etwas denken, was meist einer völligen Aufgabe des Plans gleich kommt)
- **sich etwas anders überlegen** (den ursprünglichen Plan modifizieren, was auch bedeuten kann, dass man den Plan ganz verwirft)
- **von etwas abkommen** (aufgrund anderer Ereignisse oder Pläne den ursprünglichen Plan verwerfen)

Für den Beispielsatz würde ich diese Formulierung bevorzugen:

> Er hat gestern an den Selbstmord gedacht, aber **er hat es sich** dann doch **anders überlegt**.

Der Satz funktioniert auch ohne die eingeschobenen Wort »*dann*« und »*doch*«. Ich habe sie aber aus diesen Gründen hinzugefügt:

- **dann**: Um zu verstärken, dass die Änderung des Plans nicht von Anfang an im Denken des Suizidgefährdeten präsent war, sondern erst später aufkeimte.
- **doch**: Um zu verstärken, dass die andere Überlegung im Gegensatz zum ursprünglichen Plan steht.